# I can not log in a web app that have 2 default account for log in

Tags: javascript, netbeans, web-applications, glassfish

I'm creating a web aplication with Java Netbeans 8.2. and JPA modeller. I generate the code from the model, and when I run the application the website don't let me login with the defaults
users. The professor told us that  maybe the error will be that the automatic generation code didn't create the tables account, user_athoroty, etc., the tables needed to make the login, but they are create it and the 
two defaults users added in the account table. I'm using glassfish server.
So really I don't know where is the problem, if you can help with this, I will be really thanks.

[image: Capture 1]

[image: Capture 2]

Comment: you should try to execute your sql query to get all users not from a SQL editor but from your application to check if it works. And are you sure that you have not a exception thrown from the server ? Check the logs.

Comment: I don't see any exeption from the glassfish, just a warning that says: "WARNING: Parameter 1 of type T from public void org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.context.ContextualInstanceInfo.setContextualInstance(T) is not resolvable to a concrete type.", And about to execute the SQL, what you suggest is I show in a table or something in the .html the list of users?. Remember I'm just learning and the code was generate for netbeans, and maybe my questions are silly. Again, I'm thanks for ur answers.